# From a standard deck of 52 cards, 13 cards are selected. Find the probability that they include at least three cards from each suit.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> My attempt: $\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{13}{3}^{4}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{10}{1}^{4}}{\binom{52}{13}}$
>
> I tried to consider the case if we pick exactly 3 cards from each suit then add the last card which could be any suit.

I think my attempt is incorrect, but I am not sure where? How am I suppose to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 13 cards you will need 3 suits of 3 cards and one suit of 4 cards

$$P = \frac{ \binom 41  \binom {13}3^3 \binom{13}4 }  {  \binom{52}{13} }$$

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't seem to give the same answer: Pick $3$ cards from each suit: ${13 \choose 3}$. Then pick a card from the reaming $52-12=40$: ${40 \choose 1}$. That gives ${13 \choose 3}^4(40)$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Over counting of common outcomes.

Comment: that would be counting the case that the "extra" card was a 2 and the other three of the same suit  were 3, 4, 5 as being distinct from the case that the extra card was a 3 and the other three were 2, 4, 5

Answer (score 2):

My strategy would be to note that you need to pick three cards from three suits and four cards from the fourth. So, by symmetry, the probability
you seek is $p=4p_S$ where $p_S$ is the probability you pick four spades,
three hearts, three diamonds and three clubs. Alas, I don't think that
will give the same number as you get.